# Bilinear transformation which maps $z=(1,i,-1)$ and $w=(2,i,-2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have three equations after simplifying this a bit

$a+b-2c-2d=0$

$ai+b+c-di=0$

$-a+b-2c+2d=0$

How do I proceed after obtaining these equations? Please comment after every step or I will be lost.

If you care to know, this is from the chapter Complex Variables in my book.

EDIT- my book explains it like this

a+b-2c-2d=0 ----(1)

ai+b+c-di=0-----(2)

-a+b-2c+2d=0----(3)

(1)+(3) gives 2b-4c *\I get that but want to know why we added 1+3 and not 1+2*

i.e 2b-4c=b-2c

b-2c=0 ----(4)

(2)+i X (3) gives

(1+i)b+(1-2i)c+id=0 ----- (5) *\how does this step work.. totally lost in this step*

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ real or complex?

Comment: You asked almost the same question yesterday : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812875/bilinear-transformation-which-maps-z-infty-i-0-and-w-1-i-1/1814245#1814245 Try to reproduce the steps in my answer.

Comment: check out my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is that you have 3 equations and 4 unknowns. Thus you have to consider one of the unknowns, say $c$, as a parameter, and you will obtain a unique solution in the remaining variables $(a,b,d)$ depending on this parameter. In this way, any method will give you:
$$a=6ic, \ \ \ b=2c, \ \ \ d=3ic$$
Plugging these values into
$Z=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$, and simplifying by $c$, one gets: $Z=\dfrac{6iz+2}{z+3i}$.

Comment: check out my edit

Comment: For example, begin by adding your eq. (1) and your eq. (3), you will get b=2c; then plug this result in eq. (1), you will get a+0-2d=0, i.e., a=2d ; now plug these results in eq. (2), which has not been used...

Comment: All right, when you say in your text "I get that but want to know why we added 1+3 and not 1+2" (the same operation I have done): the only reason is that you get a simpler expression in this way, with less terms...

Comment: thanks for telling me that. what about in (5), how did (1+i)b... magically appear?

Comment: No magic: if you add eq (2) and i times eq (3), you get a term $b$ coming from (2) and a term $bi$ coming from "i times eq (3)", $b+bi$ makes $(1+i)b$.

Comment: why would you want to add i though? i'm sorry if i'm asking you stupid questions but i've been struggling with this topic for 4 days now

Comment: This step looks very artificial, but if, now, in eq. (5), you plug the result $b=2d$ (obtained as eq (4)), you get : $3c+id=0$ which is equivalent with "my" $d=3ic$.

Comment: thanks a million, I finally got what you were able to get.. i.e values of a, b,  d and am ready to plug the values into the equation but i'm wondering  what to replace c with? should i find out the value of c?

Comment: No, in fact, it disappears, because it can be factored in the numerator and the denominator : $Z=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}=\dfrac{6icz+2c}{cz+3ic}=\dfrac{c(6iz+2)}{c(z+3i)}=\dfrac{6iz+2}{z+3i}$ (it has been simplified). Another way to say it is that $c$ is arbitrary, thus can be taken equal to $1$.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks a billion for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

Add the first and the third equations to get

$$(a+b-2c-2d)+(-a+b-2c+2d)=0\implies 2(b-2c)=0\implies b=2c$$

Plugging this in at the first equation, $a-2d=0\implies a=2d$.

Plugging these two into the second equation

$$2di+2c+c-di=0\implies di+3c=0$$

Comment: my book explains it like this

a+b-2c-2d=0 ----(1)

ai+b+c-di=0-----(2)

-a+b-2c+2d=0----(3)

(1)+(3) gives 2b-4c *\I get that but want to know why we added 1+3 and not 1+2\*

i.e 2b-4c=b-2c

b-2c=0 ----(4)

(2)+i X (3) gives

(1+i)b+(1-2i)c+id=0 ----- (5) *\how does this step work.. totally lost in this step\*