# Bilinear transformation which maps $z=(-1,i,−1) $ and $w=(1,i,−1)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have formed three equations
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
-a+b+c-d & = & 0 & (1)\\
ai+b+c-di & = & 0 & (2)\\
-a+b-c+d & = & 0 & (3)
\end{array}\right.$$

I also have found out a $4$th equation by adding equation $(1)$ and $(3)$:
$$-a+b=0\tag{4}\label{4}$$

Therefore $ b=a$

I am not sure what to do next.

EDIT- Should I add equation \eqref{4} and $(2)$ ?

EDIT 1- So i managed to solve it but am unsure if i have the right solution. My answer is $ w= \frac{z-1}{ k(z-2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general method that will work for all of these problems:

Given distinct $z_1,z_2,z_3$, the transformation
$$ T_{z_1,z_2,z_3}(z)=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)} $$
maps the triple $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ to $(0,1,\infty)$.

Then if $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are distinct, the map $T$ sending $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ to $(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ is given by
$$ T=T_{w_1,w_2,w_3}^{-1}T_{z_1,z_2,z_3}$$

Comment: I think my way will be easier in the long run. Recall that for every Mobius transformation $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ there is a corresponding matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, and composing/inverting Mobius transformations corresponds to multiplying/inverting matrices.

Comment: I just solved it. Is the solution w= (z-1) / k(z-2)?

Comment: You have posted in the last 48 hours a lot of questions all on the same subject. I have been answering some hours ago to one which is almost the same as this one at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814521 see also math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812875/…  Please, fly using your own wings...

Comment: Sorry to be a botheration but how can I confirm I have the right answer?

Comment: What does $k$ stand for?

Comment: I used k as a constant... or is it unnecessary? Would my solution just be this then w= (z-1) / (z-2) ?

Comment: Also, the triple $(-1,i,-1)$ has a repeat. Is one of the $-1$s supposed to be a $1$?

Comment: That's what is printed.

Comment: It's probably a typo. Assuming the second $-1$ should be a $1$, I get $z\mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Ok. Is there anyway you can vet my answer or do you think it is incorrect because the question is incorrect?

Comment: I'd ask for clarification about the question. There is no single-valued function which maps $-1$ to $1$ and also maps $-1$ to $-1$.